# htaccess rules losted when directory exists

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

this is my code at .HTACCESS file in my web server:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

This code works well, but when a directory exists the website redirect to Index of (Apache directory browsing):

For example:

1. http://www.mywebsite.com/XXXX This redirects to the URL http://www.mywebsite.com/XXXX and the page show information about XXXX. (Directory XXXX doesn't exists)
2. Directory ZZZZ exists and http://www.mywebsite.com/ZZZZ redirects to Index of (Apache directory browsing)

Finally, the question is how to redirect as 1. example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

This line disables rewriting for existing directories. Simply remove it if you always want to rewrite.